# How to use a button in a while loop in Arduino?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

So i tried to make a little quiz, it can use a lot of improvement but i would like to have a finished project before i better it. I want the user to choose the answer by pressing a button.

My code currently looks like this.

```cpp
char serialData;
int i = 1;
int redLed = 12;
int greenLed=13;
int buttonA=11;
int buttonB=10;
int buttonC=9;
int lastState = LOW;
int currentState;

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(redLed, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(greenLed, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(buttonA,INPUT);
    pinMode(buttonB,INPUT);
    pinMode(buttonC,INPUT);

    // read the state of the switch/button:
    currentState = digitalRead(buttonA);

    if(lastState == HIGH && currentState == LOW)
        Serial.println("A");

    // save the the last state
    lastState = currentState;
    delay(100);
}

void loop()
{
    vraag1();
    delay(1000);
    vraag2();
    delay(1000);
    vraag3();
    delay(1000);
    vraag4();
    delay(1000);
    vraag5();
    delay(1000);
    vraag6();
}

void vraag1()
{                                               //1
    Serial.println(" 3+3=? ");
    delay(400);
    Serial.println(" A) 6");
    delay(200);
    Serial.println(" B) 5 ");
    delay(200);
    Serial.println(" C) 4 ");
    delay(200);
    while  (Serial.available() ==0){}             //2-2

    /*
        This is the part I added to resolve the issue - but it
        does not work.
    */
    currentState = digitalRead(buttonA);
    if(lastState == HIGH && currentState == LOW)
        Serial.println("A");
    lastState = currentState;

    if (Serial.available())
    {                                             //3
        serialData = Serial.read();
        if (serialData == '6' || serialData == 'a' || serialData == 'A')
        {                                             //4
            Serial.println(" Correct ");
            i++;
            digitalWrite(greenLed, HIGH);
        }                                             //4
        else
        {                                           //5
            Serial.println(" Incorrect ");
            digitalWrite(redLed, HIGH);
        }                                         //5
    }

    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(redLed, LOW);
    digitalWrite(greenLed, LOW);
}
```

This is the code I added to try it but it doesn't work at all. Does anyone have another suggestion?

```cpp
      currentState = digitalRead(buttonA);
      if(lastState == HIGH && currentState == LOW)
        Serial.println("A");
      lastState = currentState;
```

Comment: why you are looking for high to low state transistion ? in the code ?

Comment: You have to remove the line `while  (Serial.available() ==0){}` to skip waiting for a Serial input and read the buttons immediately. Either remove Serial reading completely or combine Serial.read and digitalRead **properly**.